# Select MIN MAX together alters behaviour of query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite table with the following columns:

- timestamp
- id
- value

I want to write a query that - for each id - lists the latest timestamp with the value at that timestamp, as well as the max value for each id.

For that I wrote the following query that works as expected.

```
SELECT timestamp, MAX(value) as  max, id, value from (
    SELECT * from temperatures order by timestamp DESC
) GROUP BY ID;
```

When I now also want to calculate the min value, I alter the query:

```
SELECT timestamp, MAX(value) as  max, MIN(value) as min, id, value from (
    SELECT * from temperatures order by timestamp DESC
) GROUP BY ID;
```

The problem now is that the timestamp is not the latest timestamp anymore. Why is that?

Comment: You say that your 1st query *works as expected*, but this query does not return the `value` of the row with the latest timestamp. It returns the `timestamp` of the row with the max value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  The `SELECT` list is not compatible with the `GROUP BY`.  So, what SQLite does is bespoke processing . . . and yes, what the query does change the meaning by adding another column.

I would recommend that you write the query using window functions:

```
SELECT id, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp),
       MIN(CASE WHEN timestamp_asc = 1 THEN value END) as temp_at_min,
       MIN(CASE WHEN timestamp_desc = 1 THEN value END) as temp_at_max
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp ASC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM temperatures t
     ) t
GROUP BY ID;
```

This is standard SQL and should consistently do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I think this pointed me into the right direction. I think I can use the following query:

Comment: SELECT id, timestamp, value, MIN(value), MAX(value)
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM temperatures t
     ) t
GROUP BY ID;

Comment: Seems you're not really taking in what's being said. If id is the primary key there isn't any point grouping by it. If it's not the primary key/more unique than timestamp and value then grouping by it alone will give unpredictable results if the db even accepts it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MIN(), MAX() and FIRST_VALUE() window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
  MIN(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id) min_timestamp,
  MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id) max_timestamp,
  FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) min,
  FIRST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) max  
FROM temperatures
```

There is no need for aggregation, window functions are enough.